# How to use jbox2d / Install in NetBeans?

Tags: java, jbox2d

I'm trying to figure out how to use "jbox2d" with NetBeans and I can't find any answers or tutorials. I need it for collision and movement. I tried importing it in many different ways, none of them have worked. I just didn't do it right, and I can't find any tutorials.

Comment: It all depends on which dependency manager you are using, and if you want a self-contained jar or not. Please provide more information. What type of project do you have?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.